# What is the best practise for outputting JSON Type arrays from Table values without repetition?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, for-json

I have the following SQL data that I am trying to output as a structured JSON string as follows:

Table data

```
TableId ContainerId MaterialId  SizeId
848     1           1           1
849     1           1           2
850     1           2           1
851     1           2           2
852     1           3           1
853     1           4           1
854     2           2           1
855     2           2           2
856     2           2           3
```

JSON output

```
{
  "container": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "material": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "size": [
            {
              "id": 1
            },
            {
              "id": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "size": [
            {
              "id": 1
            },
            {
              "id": 2
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "size": [
            {
              "id": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "size": [
            {
              "id": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "material": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "size": [
            {
              "id": 1
            },
            {
              "id": 2
            },
            {
              "id": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried several ways of outputting it but I am struggling to stop duplicated Container and Material Id records. Is anyone able to demonstrate the best working practices for extracting JSON from a table such as this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it isn't pretty but this appears to work:

```
WITH
   container As (SELECT distinct containerid As id FROM jsonArray1 As container)
 , material As (SELECT distinct materialid As id, containerid As cid FROM jsonArray1 As material) 
 , size As (SELECT sizeid As id, materialid As tid, containerid As cid FROM jsonArray1 As size) 
SELECT container.id id, material.id id, size.id id
FROM container
JOIN material ON material.cid = container.id 
JOIN size     ON size.tid = material.id AND size.cid = material.cid
FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT
```

[sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8b5961/26)

AUTO will structure JSON for you, but only by following the structure of the data tables used in the query.  Since the data starts out "flat" in a single table, AUTO won't create any structure.  So the trick I applied here was to use WITH CTE's to restructure this flat data into three virtual tables whose relationships had the necessary structure.

Everything here is super-sensitive in a way that normal relational SQL would not be.  For instance, just changing the order of the JOINs will restructure the JSON hierarchy even though that would have no effect on a normal SQL query.

I also had to play around with the table and column aliases (a *lot*) to get it to put the right names on everything in the JSON.

Comment: Your method is wonderful. I was looking for such a method but I did not find it

Comment: @MeysamAsadi Thanks, it took a lot of fiddling to get this to work right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT CONCAT('{"container": [',string_agg(json,','),']}') as json
FROM 


  (SELECT CONCAT('{"id:"',CAST(ContainerId as nvarchar(100)),
       ',"material":[{',string_agg(json,','),'}]}') as json,
       dense_rank() over(partition by ContainerId order by ContainerId) rnk
  FROM
     (SELECT ContainerId ,MaterialId,CONCAT('"id":',CAST(MaterialId as nvarchar(100))
           ,',"size":[',string_agg('{"id":' + CAST(SizeId as nvarchar(100)) + '}',','),']') as json
         
     FROM tb  
     GROUP BY ContainerId,MaterialId) T
  GROUP BY ContainerId) T

GROUP BY rnk
```

*demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=720ce0adf4b153a374331f7978d60875)*